# How to boot from CD? (Asus X541NA)

Tags: linux, boot, bios, uefi

I am trying to boot from CD or USB on an Asus X541NA laptop. In the boot options, the only option is to boot into Windows. I have already disabled Secure Boot and Fast Boot. I do not know if it is UEFI or BIOS . I would assume UEFI because it's a new computer, but the BIOS/UEFI menu refers to itself as 'BIOS Utility' and the Main menu refers to 'BIOS Information' and 'BIOS Vendor'. The version is 314, vendor is America Megatrends, GOP version is 10.0.1036 (not sure if any of that is relevant). I do not see any option for Legacy or CSM, or to switch between UEFI and BIOS/Legacy.
In the boot menu, the priorities list only has Windows as an option. I do have the option to 'add new boot option'. When trying to add a boot option, I have to select path for boot option. When selecting a path for the boot option, I am first asked to select a file system. I only have one option which is PCI(12|0)\DevicePath(Type 3, SubType 12)HD(Part1.Sig44fa2e2a-a76b-478e-863a-a9675829c331). I am forced to select this as it is the only option. After selecting it, I am asked to select a file to boot. My only option is EFI. Within EFI I can choose either Microsoft or Boot. Within Boot my only option is bootx64.efi. Within Microsoft I can select Boot or Recovery. Within Recovery there is no option. Within Boot I have languages to choose from. When selecting one (en-US for example) I then have no options. So ultimately out of all the options, all I can do is EFI-Boot-bootx64.efi. I tried creating a new boot option with bootx64.efi but that doesn't change anything, I still can't boot from CD or USB.
I also tried restarting my computer with a live CD in the CD drive and a live flash drive in a USB port, and they still don't show up as boot options.
I apologize if some of the information I posted is irrelevant, or if there is anything I left out that I should have included.
I don't care about installing an operating system, I only want to be able to boot from a live CD and/or live flash drive.
What should I try next?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Before reaching out for support from a 3rd party, the best thing to do is to read the manual: https://www.asus.com/Laptops/X541NA/HelpDesk_Manual/

It shows the boot options you are looking for in “Advanced Mode” of the BIOS Utility.

Comment: Thank you for the reply, but I already went into Advanced Mode. That's where I had the options I described in the original post. The only boot options available are Windows and the test boot option I created. I am wondering how I can add a CD or flash drive to the boot options.

Comment: @anon3140 It shows the options in the manual including screenshots. I don’t know what else to say.

Comment: @anon3140 disable fast boot, disable secure boot, and enable csm boot.  That’s usually all it takes. Don’t forget to reboot after changing these options. Sometimes they don’t take effect until a restart.

Comment: My BIOS advanced menu looks similar to the screenshots, but there is no option for booting from CD or flash drive.
I have already disabled fast boot and disabled secure boot, and I have restarted several times since then. I do not have an option for CSM boot. The screenshot in the manual shows an option to enable CSM boot, but my BIOS screen (while looking almost identical to that in the screenshot in the manual) does not have that option.

Comment: unplug the hard drive just to see if it will force a boot from CD

Comment: @anon3140 silly question, are you sure the cd-rom is working? Can you put a disc in and see it in Windows? You might also try installing the latest BIOS update. After all that, the option has to be there. This is system firmware, so it’s simplistic in nature and identical from machine to machine. There has to be a combination of options that will enable the features you are looking for. Keep looking.